# To get ip address, mac address in powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, mac-address

I am trying to fetch the ip address and mac address.Below code is working very fine but not for windows R2 , any one has any suggestions ?

Primary Ip

```
(get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration|Where {$_.Ipaddress.length -gt 1}).IPAddress | Select-object -index 0
```

Primary MAC:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where {$_.ipenabled -EQ $true}).Macaddress | select-object -first 1
```

Comment: What's "windows R2"? What error or repsonse do you receive?

Comment: its windows 2008 R2 enterprise edition. No error I get, but it does not return any value at all !

Comment: another example:
PS C:\Windows\system32> $disk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName .
| Select-Object Size,FreeSpace
PS C:\Windows\system32> $disk.Size
PS C:\Windows\system32> $disk

Size                                    FreeSpace
----                                    ---------

53684989952                             5054779392
53683941376                             14109630464
268432306176                            21086539776
53683941376                             42046615552



PS C:\Windows\system32> $disk.FreeSpace
PS C:\Windows\system32>

Comment: Do you have PowerShell v2 installed? Check with `$psversiontable`.

Comment: Add more information by editing your question. Reading code and errors in the comments sucks.

Comment: I wonder if this a Powersshell issue. Does WMI run at alll or is it maybe broken/corrupt? See e.g. https://support.quest.com/vworkspace/kb/88861/how-to-repair-or-fully-rebuild-windows-wmi-repository

Comment: You can simply use Get-NetAdapter, if you just need MAC address and not the IP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not had W2K8R2 servers in years, but try it this way...

```
Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration | 
Select-Object -Property @{
    Name = 'IPAddress'
    Expression = {($PSItem.IPAddress[0])}
},MacAddress | 
Where IPAddress -NE $null

IPAddress      MacAddress       
---------      ----------       
10.0.0.11     50:7B:9D:96:5C:51
```